# ZF2 : Add a Login widget in the template

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am currently building my website, and I'm getting blocked with this issue.

I want to have a layout with a side column, and a middle column.

In the middle column, there will be the Content.
In the side column, there will be the login form, or the "Welcome XXX" if already logged. So that you could log-in on every page.

Problem is : I don't know how to create the widget/view helper which would manage all the logging form/welcome message.

Currently, I have a whole controller dedicated to login, which works great. But that doesn't do what I need :).

Any idea or simple explanation would be appreciated :p.

Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so I found a solution. I don't know if it's the best one, but it actualy works.
I've made it with a mix of what I could find on the internet.

If you've never built an authentication service, check this tutorial :
http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/zend-framework-2-create-login-authentication-using-authenticationservice-with-rememberme/

So the main solution is to use a view-helper. So that in our layout we would just have to call something like :

```
$this->Login_widget();
```

You have to create a custom view-helper :

```
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Application\Form\LoginForm;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;

class Loginhelper extends AbstractHelper{

    protected $serviceLocator;
    protected $authService;

    public function __invoke(){
        $this->authService = $this->serviceLocator->get('AuthService');

        if($this->authService->hasIdentity()){
            return $this->getView()->render('partial/login', array('getIdentity' => $this->authService->getIdentity()));
        }
        else{
            $form=new LoginForm();
            return $this->getView()->render('partial/login', array('form' => $form));
        }
    }

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceManager $serviceLocator){
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }
}
```

I need to get two things in this view-helper.

1. My login form, in order to display it in my view.
2. The ServiceManager (or ServiceLocator), to get my Authentication service (called AuthService).

Getting the login form is realy easy. Just include it.
Getting your service is done in your Module.php.

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Login_widget' => function ($helperPluginManager) {
                $serviceLocator = $helperPluginManager->getServiceLocator();
                $viewHelper = new View\Helper\Loginhelper();
                $viewHelper->setServiceLocator($serviceLocator);
                return $viewHelper;
            }
        )
    );
```

}

With this code, your give the serviceLocator to the viewhelper.
And now, you can retrieve your service right inside your viewhelper. Again, I'm not quite sure if it's the best solution, but it works.

Your view helper is now working. You just have to create the content of your view helper.
You can either return a partial (as I did), or return your HTML code (good for small things).

If you use partials, don't forget to declare them in your module.config.php.

In my case, I test if the user is logged. If he is, I print something like "Welcome dude", if not, I pass the form object to my partial, and display it in my view. The whole authentication process is done in a specified controller.

Now, in your layout, you just have to call your viewhelper.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="The_login_widget_div">
    <?php     
        echo $this->Login_helper();   
    ?>
    </div>

    <div id="main_content_div">
    <?php echo $this->content; ?> 
    </div>            
</div>
```

And this is it. I hope it helped someone. And btw, this is with ZF 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Also maybe you want to see Zf2Plugin for generate dynamic content (such as login form)
[zf2Plugin](https://github.com/mbrostami/zf2Plugin)