# Zend Navigation and RBAC

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-navigation, rbac, zend-acl, zend-layout

I am developing a ZF2 based site. I have a main navigation which stays same regardless of the visitor/user status. Need to add another component/nav, which will depend on the user's status and role. For a visitor the items will be

- Register
- Login
- EN (Actually a drop-down, with other available language)

For a logged-in normal user, it will display

- Profile
- Logout
- EN (Language selector as mentioned above)

And for some users with specific roles/permission there will be additional items

I want to use RBAC, as ACL seems bloated, and also just to check if the current logged in user/role has additional items, I need to load the complete ACL (and we got around 15+ different types of roles).

I spent some time thinking how I have achieve this, so following are some ideas I have.

1. I create an empty navigation container, and create a factory. In the factory, I access the Authentication and RBAC and add the pages depending on the the user's status/role.
2. I create a fully loaded navigation with all the possible pages, then in the factory, with the help of Authentication and RBAC I hide the pages I don't want to show.
3. ## rd option is to use a view helper which will get RBAC via ServiceLayer and generate the navigation. (As discussed in [ZF2 how to display tweets in layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790856/zf2-how-to-display-tweets-in-layout) and [ZF2 : Add a Login widget in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793655/zf2-add-a-login-widget-in-the-template).
4. Or I can create a controller-plugin or just a method in module.php, and listen to the MVC_Render or MVC_Dispatch event and generate the desired navigation and add the output to a view variable.

PS: I need to use a partial as I need to add some CSS class to the language selection section. Also the navigation will be displayed in the layout.

Answer (score 3):

I am using [ZfcRbac](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcRbac) and I am doing it as the following, you can display the navigation based on user roles and the navigation items permission as the following:

First add a permission to your navigation item as the following:

`'permission' => 'edit-profile',`

Then attach a listener in the `onBootstrap` as the following:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->getSharedManager()->attach(
        'Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\AbstractHelper', 
        'isAllowed', 
        array('\Application\Listener\RbacListener', 'accept')
    );
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
}
```

Then create a class `Application\Listener\RbacListener` as the following:

```
public function accept(Event $event) { 
    $event->stopPropagation();

    $accepted = true;

    $serviceLocator = $event->getTarget()->getServiceLocator()->getServiceLocator();
    $rbac           = $serviceLocator->get('ZfcRbac\Service\Rbac');

    $params = $event->getParams();
    $page = $params['page'];

    $permission = $page->getPermission();

    if ($permission) {
        $accepted = $rbac->isGranted($permission);
    }

    return $accepted;
}
```

and by this when you display the menu it will be filtered based on the permission and roles, for example if you do `echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu()` then only the menu items that the user has permission on will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, works like a charm. Could you please clarify a bit about $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager); Why do we need this?

Comment: I tried your solution @Mohammad but I get the following error: Strict Standards: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method Application\Listener\RbacListener::accept() should not be called statically in /home/.../zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php on line 468 - Has something changed with the current versions?

Comment: Here is short tutorial on the same attempt by @Mohammed ZeinEddin that works with the latest versions of ZF2 and ZfcRbac: http://blog.webdevilopers.net/?p=9

Comment: function accept in RbacListener should be a static one